# How to derive one TeX-Format from another

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, format-files

Let's say I want to write my own TeX-format for learning purpose, how can I easily derive from plain.fmt (or better xetex.fmt)?

Comment: You can't use the `.fmt` files: perhaps you mean the source files such as `plain.tex` or `etex.src` and 'add ons' such as `xetex.ini` (used in the format-building process to add 'goodies')?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Main'? Can I simply \input them?

Comment: You can `\input` the files, but most of these are set up to dump a format. You might look at some of the LaTeX-related ones to see how to get around that (`latex.ltx` includes `\dump`, so e.g. `xelatex.ini` has to work around it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, did some research and it seems fairly easy:

```
\let\damp=\dump  % save old meaning of \dump in \damp
\let\dump=\relax % tell \dump to do nothing 
\input xetex.ini % or plain.tex or whatever you want to derive from
\let\dump=\damp  % recover original meaning of \dump from \damp

% Your own extensions on top of whatever you loaded a few lines ago
```

A small MWE which shows whats going on:

```
$ cat mwe.tex
\show\dump
\let\damp=\dump
\show\damp
\let\dump=\relax
\show\dump
\input xetex.ini
\let\dump=\damp
\show\dump

$ xetex -ini -progname=xetex -etex mwe.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
> \dump=\dump.
l.1 \show\dump

? 
> \damp=\dump.
l.3 \show\damp

? 
> \dump=\relax.
l.5 \show\dump

? 
[… snipped output coming from xetex.ini …]
> \dump=\dump.
l.8 \show\dump

? 
)
*\bye
No pages of output.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

Perhaps it might be possible to even extend this one to detect if used in ordinary TeX (the ASCII one), luaTeX, or XeTeX to load the appropriate base-format and does some other magic around that (e.g.: defining different default fonts, depending on the capabilities of the engine). Ways to test this could use `\ifx\undefined\engineOnlyStuff` (if you can guarantee e-TeX to be enabled, you can also use `ifdefined`) to determine the underlying engine:

```
\ifx\XeTeXversion\undefined
  This might be anything, but not XeTeX!
\else
  You are using XeTeX!
\fi
```

This typesets “You are using XeTeX” if you use XeTeX and at least on my machine classic-ASCII-TeX gave me “This might be anything, but not XeTeX!”.

Anyway, I am fine with the static approach I am using right now.

Comment: You can certainly build files which have engine-selective paths: it's not different from doing the same in a use-time package. You still of course have to build one `.fmt` file per engine.

Comment: Ich am aware of the one Format per engine stuff, also a xetex only format is sufficient for me I just gave a pointer to whomever might Come to the Same problem. But you are right I should edit my answer and Point that Out, as soon as  I'm on my Laptop.